# Proving directly Trace-Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

I am having difficulties in proving directly the following statement:

I know that similar matrices have the same eigenvalues and that implies that their traces are the equal (if eigenvalues exist).

I would like to know if to prove directly that $Tr(A)$= $Tr(U^{-1}AU)$ for a general  × matrix, using the definitions of Trace and matrix multiplication.

I found this on the internet:

$Tr(AB)=Tr(BA)$ implies that  if U is a square matrix n x n and it is invertible then

$Tr(A)$= $Tr(U^{-1}AU)$.

However I do not understand how can I prove directly that $Tr(A)$= $Tr(U^{-1}AU)$ using the fact that $Tr(AB)=Tr(BA)$

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to apply the properties of trace. If you set $A = U^{-1}$ and $B = AU$ then $$Tr(AB) = Tr(U^{-1}AU) = Tr(BA) = Tr(A U U^{-1}) = Tr(AI) = Tr(A)$$.

Comment: In this part 'Tr(AI)' is Trace of A*Identity matrix?

Comment: Yes, because $UU^{-1} = I$.

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much for your help